# Sync issues in reading and writing from same text file using 2 different programs

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, pyglet

I have a text file which acts as a source for program A and sink for program B. Program B responsible for updating the file does so in regular intervals of time and always overwrite the file. Program A that is reading the file is constantly reading it and takes in the updated values whenever that happens. It works fine for sometime. But eventually, Program A crashes. The error shown is:

```
File "/home/../baba_rect.py", line 61, in on_draw
     if (int(a[core_id]) <= 100):
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is the code for Program A:

```
    import sys, time, math, os, random
    from pyglet.gl import *

    red = [255,0,0]
    green = [0,255,0]
    blue = [0,0,255]
    black = [0,0,0]

    dim_x = 2;
    dim_y = 2;

    window = pyglet.window.Window()

    label = pyglet.text.Label('Simulation', 
                              font_name='Times New Roman', 
                              font_size=16,
                              color=(204,204,0,255),      #red font (255,0,0) opacity=255
                              x=window.width, y=window.height,
                              anchor_x='right', anchor_y='top') 

    class FilledSquare:
        def __init__(self, width, height, xpos, ypos):
            self.xpos = xpos
            self.ypos = ypos
            self.angle = 0
            self.size = 1
            x = width/2.0
            y = height/2.0
            self.vlist = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(4, ('v2f', [-x,-y, x,-y, -x,y, x,y]), ('t2f', [0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1]))  
        def draw(self,w,h,x,y):
            self.width=w
            self.height=h
            self.xpos=x
            self.ypos=y
            glPushMatrix()
            glTranslatef(self.xpos, self.ypos, 0)
            self.vlist.draw(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)        
            glPopMatrix()


    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        glClearColor(0, 0.3, 0.5, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        label.draw()

        for i in range(0,dim_x):
            for j in range(0,dim_y):
                print i,",",j
                #read file
                f = open('r.txt', 'r')
                a = f.readline()
                a = a.rstrip('\n')
                a = a.split(" ")
                f.close()
                #core_id
                core_id = j*dim_x + i;
                if (int(a[core_id]) <= 100):
                    color = red
                elif (int(a[core_id]) <= 200):
                    color = green
                elif (int(a[core_id]) <= 300):
                    color = blue
                else:
                    color = black

                glColor3f(color[0], color[1],color[2])
                squares[i+j].draw(60,60,i*50+200,j*50+200)     

    squares = [FilledSquare(30, 30, 0, 0), FilledSquare(30, 30, 0, 0), FilledSquare(30, 30, 0, 0), FilledSquare(30, 30, 0, 0)]   # 2x2

    pyglet.app.run()
```

This is how the text file *r.txt* may look like at any instant in time:

> 10 20 120 235

I believe the reason for the crash is because at that point, it so happens that both Pgm A and Pgm B are accessing the file simultaneously and Pgm A reads a *" "*  instead of the number which can't be converted to int(). If my conclusion is indeed true, then how can I overcome this?

Or: Is it possible to make pyglet.app.run() sensitive to any change to *r.txt*? i.e. Pgm A runs only when there is a change in the text file, thus avoiding the conflict.

Comment: Replace int() with float() in line 61, elif (int(a[core_id]) <= 200): to elif (float(a[core_id]) <= 200):. The error is that your program is trying to read integers, int, while getting float numbers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that is the reason. Because I am never writing anything *float* in r.txt. It only has integers seperated by space. Also, I tried your suggestion and the error now is:

>>    File "/home/../baba_rect.py", line 61, in on_draw
        if (float(a[core_id]) <= 100):
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The Value error message says you're using int to read float. When you've now corrected it you're getting another error, that your list is out of range, IndexError: list index out of range, try looping for i in range(0,dim_x, +1). You also need a 'return' statement under the loop for j in range(0,dim_y):, add "return a"

Comment: also change for i in range(0,dim_x) to for i in range(0,len(dim_x)) in both for loops.

Comment: print a[core_id] before convert to int to see the invalid value

Answer (score 0):

Use `flock`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock.

Listening for a file change is done with inotify: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify. However, this is not a solution for proper file locking.

Updated:

```
f = open('filename', 'r')
fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX) # Get exclusive lock
do_stuff(f)
fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
f.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I am new in python and don't have much experience in file handling either. Can you give me a little more detail. Appreciate it anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've added an example for flock.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. But it still don't seem to help. I am getting the same error as I last reported.
`File "/home/../baba_rect.py", line 66, in on_draw`
    a[core_id]=a[core_id].rstrip('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What is the locking supposed to do? If Pgm B locks r.txt, then does that mean the Pgm A will suspend and wait till Pgm B unlocks the file to perform its job on r.txt? Sorry, I am new to this concept. Where should I put the lock?

Comment: @VindRaider both programs must use flock. If A flock's a file, and then B tries to open and edit it, the edit will be successful, and will likely screw with A. However, if A flock's a file, and then B tries to flock it, the call to flock will block until A funlock's it. That's the behaviour you're going for.